# How do you find a element of a two dimensional array using the index? python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]
```

what should I do to find 5 in a?

I tried using:

`a[[2],[2]]`

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Each sublist in `a` can be accessed with an index starting at 0. ie:

```
print a[0] # = [1,2,3]
```

you apply the same index principle to the elements within each sublist

```
     |  0  | |  1  | |  2  |
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] 
index 0 1 2   0 1 2   0 1 2

print a[1][1] # = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You need indices 1 and 1, remember arrays are 0 indexed. 2, 2 would be 9.

```
values

1     2     3

4     5     6

7     8     9

indices

0,0   0,1  0,2

1,0   1,1  1,2

2,0   2,1  2,2
```