# Index of an item within a list within a list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Say that I have the following the code:

```
names_list = [['Abby', 'Albert'], ['Bert', 'Bob'], ['Gina', 'Greg']]
```

Now how would you print Albert ?
To print 'abby', 'albert' I'd use:

```
print (names_list[0])
```

How would you use an item within the list though?
Hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

```
print (names_list[0][1]) # prints Albert
```

To answer the question in your comment:

```
names_list = [['Abby', ['name', 'lastname']]]

print(names_list[0][1][1]) # prints lastname


              |            0               |  # names_list[0]
names_list = [['Abby', ['name', 'lastname']]]
               |  0  | |         1        |   # two elems within names_list[0]
                        | 0  |  |    1   |    # two elems in names_list[0][1]
```

Comment: The example I gave was 2 levels. Say that I have another list instead of 'albert' and I would like to use the 4th item there, would I just use: print (names_list[0][1][3] ?

Comment: take a look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940015/how-do-you-find-a-element-of-a-two-dimensional-array-using-the-index-python/19940114#19940114

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 steps

```
Python 3.3.1 (default, Sep 25 2013, 19:29:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> names_list = [['Abby', 'Albert'], ['Bert', 'Bob'], ['Gina', 'Greg']]
>>> 
>>> firstset = names_list[0]
>>> print (firstset)
['Abby', 'Albert']
>>> 
>>> albert = firstset[1]
>>> print (albert)
Albert
```

Or you can do it in one step

```
>>> print (names_list[0][1])
Albert
```